# Why does $\pi$ cancel out when converting angle measures from radians to degrees?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, pi, angle

Can someone tell me why $\pi$ cancels out from this fraction when converting radians to degrees?

[image]

Comment: Hint: $\pi\; rad = 180^{\circ}$.

Comment: A matter of scaling, $2 \pi$ rad is the same as $360^o$ so $\pi$ rad is the same as $180^o$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$ rad $= \frac {180}{\pi}$ degrees, so $\frac {7 \pi}{8}$ radians = $\frac {7 \pi}{8} \cdot \frac {180}{\pi}$ degrees.  The $\pi$ gets canceled with part of the conversion factor.